# xcodebuild fails on the 'write auxiliary files' step

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I am doing a clean then archive:

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace \
           -scheme MyScheme \
           -archivePath /Library/......./outputfolder/MyApp.xcarchive \
           clean archive
```

I get this error about 50% of the time.

```
The following build commands failed:
    Write auxiliary files
```

Its reported twice in the apple developer forums (but not yet on StackOverflow as far as I am aware).

- https://devforums.apple.com/message/938564#938564
- https://devforums.apple.com/message/953949#953949

Has anyone found the cause or a workaround?

Comment: Also seeing this error, maybe related to cocoapods

Comment: Yes - I am also using cocoapods this is a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue was fixed with the release of XCode 5.1.1  The [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/developertools/rn-xcode/xc5_release_notes/xc5_release_notes.html) had 2 vague mentions of 2 bug fixes on the 'Build System' which I guess fixes the issue.

The updates should happen automatically.  If not go to the app store and install both the command line tools update and the latest Xcode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing this error with a build that was using cocoapods.

Updating to the latest (0.31.1 as of writing) fixed the issue for me.

This can be done with: `(sudo) gem install cocoapods`

Comment: Nice idea.  Sadly though `pod --version` yields `0.33.1` for me too.  I am still able to reproduce the issue every 3 or so builds, so I don't believe that updating is the fix :(

Comment: Actually I just ran a pod install anyway and I ended on version `0.32.1`.  Not sure how I have gone backwards.  I now can't reproduce it, however, it makes no sense that that would fix it since updating cocoapods has not modified any of my project files and from what I understand cocoa pods doesn't actually do anything in the build phase, it only modifies the .xcodeproject settings.  So it could not have had an effect right?

Comment: Actually, just reproduced the issue.  So updating cocoapods is unfortunately not the solution.